# Pointers in C programming with double precision

Tags: c, pointers, double, precision

Ok so this what I must do but i can't make it work:

a) Change to float instead of integers. And assign 0.3 as starting value to "u".

b) Use double precision instead of integers. Asign 0.3x10^45 as starting value for "u".

c) Use characters instead of integers. Assign starting value as 'C' for "u".

```
#include <stdio.h>
main ()
{
int u = 3;
int v;
int *pu;
int *pv;
pu = &u;
v = *pu;
pv = &v;

printf("\nu=%d     &u=%X    pu=%X  *pu=%d", u, &u, pu, *pu);
printf("\n\nv=%d    &v=%X    pv=%X  *pv=%d", v, &v, pv, *pv);
}
```

I'll be really grateful if anyone could modify my code to do the things above. Thanks

Comment: What is your expected result?  What are you getting? Is this code crashing?

Comment: I wanna modify it not to expect certain results but to demonstrate the use of double precision

Comment: If you have no expected results, then how can you evaluate the "correctness" of the code?

Comment: The OP's prof/TA will evaluate the "correctness" of the code.

Comment: @MartinJames There must still be some expected criteria for some kind of result. "demonstrate use of double precision" is not a well designed programming problem or homework.  `double d = 1.234;` is a demonstration of use of double precision

Comment: This is the homework I have, but I'm as confused as you guys are, I thought maybe there was a solution or something to do with the code. thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is testing a few things. First do you know your types? You are expected to know that a floating pointing number is declared with `float`, a double precision number with `double`, and a character with `char`.

Second you are expected to know how to assign a literal value to those different types. For the float literal you are probably expected to use `0.3f`, since without that suffix it would be double precision by default (although in this context it isn't going to make any difference). For the double, you are expected to know how to use scientific notation (the literal value should be `0.3e45`). The character literal I would hope is fairly obvious to you.

Finally you are expected to know the various type characters used in the `printf` format specification. Both single and double precision numbers use the same type characters, but you have a choice of `%e`, `%f` or `%g`, depending on your requirements. I tend to use `%g` as a good general purpose choice, but my guess is they are expecing you to use `%e` for the double (because that forces the use of scientific notation) and possibly `%f` for the float - it depends what you have been taught. For a character you use `%c`.

Also, note that you should only be replacing the `%d` type characters in the format strings. The `%X` values are used to output a hexadecimal representation of the pointers (`&u` and `pu`). A pointer isn't going to change into a floating point value or a character just because the type that is being pointed to has changed - an address is always an integer when you are writing it out.